# uses of fontawesome in css platform

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome icons in CSS3 as background. I already tried this CSS:

```
content:"<i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>";font-family: FontAwesome
```

However, it's not working. I want to use font awesome and I don't know how. Please let me know.

Comment: Basic syntax highlighting shows that even if this could work (it can't, `content` inserts text, not HTML) it wouldn't.

Comment: here you go -> http://codepen.io/astrotim/details/IjJzL

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go back to the font awesome website and read up about it, look at some examples of how to use it.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/